# Magento 2.0 vs 2.1 - which is better to use right now?

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.0

I am currently doing development on Magento 2.0.4 and i need to deploy my site in 1 month.

So the question is: Is it better to keep using Magento 2.0 or should i move to 2.1. And Magento 2.1 has admin structure changes that i'll have to do as well, like admin tabs are removed from 2.1 etc.

Thanks

Comment: Obviously the newer version. Magento 2.0.4 was never meant to be for production. There are many improvement in 2.1 so you should go for it.

Comment: @Hm hmm thanks, yes i got your point. Is 2.1 stable enough for production? I am just curious on moving to 2.1 as there is not much help for it.

Comment: Yeah its stable enough for production, obviously it does have have some bugs but most of them are in 2.0.* anyway. There shouldn't be that much complications in moving to a higher version, the module format is pretty much the same.